# Stripe not working on windows server, works on localhost and on previous server

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I'm having problems with Stripe payments. I had a website hosted on digital ocean and everything was working fine. Recently I had to change the hosting situation to a windows server and now (I don't understand why) Stripe isn't working (can't make new subscriptions for example).

I've been reading some stuff and it might have something to do with the SSL certificate (it's secured on Chrome but not on Firefox - used ZeroSSL) but I'm not sure if someone as some idea and can help, I'll truly appreciate it.

I'm currently using test keys until I solve the situation. The website is [ibas](https://www.ibasim.com).
Bellow is the code from the server:

buySubscription.js

```
let checkoutHandler;

$(document).ready(function() {

function init(){
    
     //configure stripe (doing this here will speed up the payment)
     checkoutHandler = StripeCheckout.configure(stripeConfigObject);
}

function updatePriceAndDetails(){

    //get selected subscription options
    let package_name = $('#subscriptionName').val();
    let package_period = $('#subscriptionPeriod').val();

    //subs is an array of objects with all subscription details and is declared in buySubscription.ejs
    //filter subs with the options selected
    let subsFiltered= subs.filter(function(v, i, arr){
        return v.name == package_name; 
    });

    subsFiltered = subsFiltered.filter(function(v, i, arr){
        return v.renewalPeriod == package_period; 
    });
    //update price
    $('#subscriptionPriceValue').html( subsFiltered[0].price );
    
    //update the details
    //hide all details except the currently selected package
    $('.subscription-package').not('.'+package_name).hide();
    $('.subscription-package.'+package_name).show();
}//function


// Start stripe buy API
$('#buySubscription').on('click', function(e){
    //start stripe API
    checkoutHandler.open({
        token: handleToken, //callback function
    });
});

function handleToken(token) {
    
    token.packageId = $('#subscriptionId').val();
    $('.working-wait').show();

    fetch("/subscricoes/pagamento", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        body: JSON.stringify(token)
    })
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        if (!response.ok){
            $('#buySubscription').hide()
            $('#paymentFail').show();
            $('.working-wait').hide();
            throw response;
            return;
        }
          
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(output => {
        $('#buySubscription').hide()
        $('#paymentSuccess').show();
        $('.working-wait').hide();
        console.log("Purchase succeeded:", output);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        $('#buySubscription').hide()
        $('#paymentFail').show();
        $('.working-wait').hide();
        console.log("Purchase failed:", err);
    })
}

init();
});//document ready
```

[Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlAhJ.png)

subscription.js

```
//process payment - restricted to logged users
router.post('/pagamento', auth.isLoggedIn, asyncMiddleware( async (req, res) => {
//get user
let user = req.user;
let customer;

//check if user has already a subscription active
//userSub = await UserSubscription.findOne({_user: user, 'stripeSubscripton.status':'active' }); //should be only one but can be more
//subscription already exists
// if( userSub ){
//   res.status(500).send({error: "User already has a subscription"});
//   return;
// }

// if user is not a stripe customer
if( !user.stripeCustomer ){
  //create customer in stripe
  customer = await customers.create({ email: user.email });
  
  logger.info(`customer created`, { meta:  customer });
  
  //update stripeId for the user
  await User.update({_id: user._id}, {stripeCustomer: customer});
  //add stripeId to the user object just so we don't need to query db again
  user.stripeCustomer = customer;
 
}else{
  //get the customer on stripe
  customer = await customers.retrieve(user.stripeCustomer.id).catch( async () => {
    
      //normaly deleted customers can still be found and used but in this rare situation we can still create one
      let newCustomer = await customers.create({ email: user.email });
      
      logger.error(`customer is unreacheable, creating new`, { meta:  newCustomer });
      
      await User.update({_id: user._id}, {stripeCustomer: newCustomer});
      user.stripeCustomer = newCustomer;

      return newCustomer
  });
 
  //a deleted customer is unusable so create a new one
  if(customer.deleted){
    customer = await customers.create({ email: user.email });
    
    logger.warn(`customer retrieved but is deleted, creating new`, { meta:  customer });
    
    await User.update({_id: user._id}, {stripeCustomer: customer});
    user.stripeCustomer = newCustomer;
  }
}//else

//still unable to find stripe customer
if( !customer.id ){
  logger.error(`purchaise failed - no customer id`, { meta:  customer });

  return res.status(500).send({error: "Purchase Failed"});
}

//attach source to customer
await stripe.customers.createSource(customer.id, {
  source: req.body.id
});

//find selected subscription plan in stripe
let selectedSubscription = await Subscription.findOne({subscriptionId: req.body.packageId});

//res.send(selectedSubscription);return;
let plan = await plans.retrieve(selectedSubscription.stripePlanId);

//create subscription
let subscription = await subs.create(user.stripeCustomer.id, plan.id);



if(subscription.id){

    //first pull the document if it exist
    await User.update(
      {
        '_id':user._id
      }, 
      {
        '$pull': {
            'stripeCustomer.subscriptions.data': {id: subscription.id}
        }
      }
    );
    //now insert with push (if it existed before it was removed with 
    pull)
    await User.update(
          {
            '_id':user._id
          }, 
          {
            '$push': {
                'stripeCustomer.subscriptions.data': subscription
            }
          }
      );
    logger.info(`subscription completed`, { meta:  subscription });
    res.status(200).send({subscription: subscription});
}else{
  logger.error(`subscription failed`, { meta:  subscription });
  res.status(500).send({error: "Subscription Failed"});
}

}))
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is the error being caught in your `.catch()` code?  If so, could you include the exact output of the error here?

Comment: @RyanM I added a printscreen of the error, I'm sorry but I couldn't copy it as a log

Comment: So it seems like you are getting a 404 error when attempting your `fetch()` request.  Can you confirm the resource at `/subscricoes/pagamento` exists and is ready to respond?

Comment: @RyanM I added the piece of code for that situation, I think everything is working on that end. The website was working on digital ocean and I just changed the server where it's hosted, so no code changes, so I'm thinking the problem comes from some configuration in the server or SSL, but I'm not knowledgeable enough to now why/where

Comment: @RyanM also, conlicted on why would this work on localhost and not the website

Comment: The resources you are trying to reach cannot be found now that it's hosted on digital ocean.  Can you check the full URL (method + domain + suffix) to make sure the request is going to the right domain?  E.g. not `http://locahost//subscricoes/pagamento` but `https://<domain>.com/subscricoes/pagamento`

Comment: @RyanM I can't reach any of them. I don't understand how this can happen if there was no change in the code :/